# .htaccess rewrite cond/rule and hide url paremeters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-parameters

I got a htaccess in my Root directory.

My files path http://example.com/folder1/folder2/index.php?country=eu&lang=en

I made this in htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?anothersite.com$   
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /folder1/folder2/index.php?country=$1&lang=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /folder1/folder2/index.php [L]
```

And looks like this

> http://example.com/index.php?country=eu&lang=en

But i want like this -> http://example.com/eu-en

Is there a way to do this in htaccess?

**EDIT:**
I have to use rewrite cond, because im redirecting to folders depends of host.

**EDIT 2: SOLUTION**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?anothersite.com$   
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,2})-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /folder1/folder2/index.php?country=$1&lang=$2 [QSA]
```

Thanks to answers, it is working now. But after that i got the css and js errors on website. Then i changed css and js paths /folder1/folder2/css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append with the [QSA] (query string append) tag. Try

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,2})/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [QSA]
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: This won`t work, you can validate it here https://htaccess.madewithlove.be

Comment: You must replace `/` with `-`

Comment: hi there. its working but my css and js files get errors. can't locate them. How do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([^/]+)$ index.php?country=$1&lang=$2 [QSA]
```

Comment: When i add thiss code all my css and js has gone, what should i do?

Comment: Is there any other rule working apart from this then write it at bottom of your code also you can use `<base href="/">` tag in head section of your view file.

Comment: Yes. I'm redirecting to folders based on my host. For example, if host example.com then i call folder1/folder2/index.php, else if example1.com i call folder3/folder4/index.php